# checking unicode with special characters

Tags: python, regex, unicode-string

I have unicode strings like

`u'0d7a6b6b37682bab6d8eda97cda4bad7'`

and

`u'Brauers, A.'`

I would like to distinguish between two of these. I tried using `regex` with `\p{Alphabet}` but it does not work with the second example as the second example contains `,` and `.`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Turn it around; check for numbers instead?

Comment: You'll have to give a fuller description of what characterizes the two strings.  Is the first always 36 characters?  Always all hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing might be to check for non-hex digits:

```
if re.match(r'[^0-9a-f]', my_string):
    # This is a u'Brauers, A.' kind of string
else:
    # This is a u'0d7a6b6b37682bab6d8eda97cda4bad7' kind of string
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check for hex digits?

```
>>> re.match(r'^[0-9a-f]*$', u'0d7a6b6b37682bab6d8eda97cda4bad7') != None
True
>>> re.match(r'^[0-9a-f]*$', u'Brauers, A.') != None
False
```